# Multiple directories in the same tree

Tags: gradle

How do I specify multiple dirs for the same fileTree in gradle.  Is this possible?

Say I have

```
def files = fileTree(
    dir: "src/test/groovy")
}
```

and I want to also add in another folder?

Reason I ask is, I want to reference multiple folders and files in this construct, not just the one fileTree

```
task testLibraryJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'testlib'
    from files
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use an **array** of fileTree objects to give multiple directories to your testLibraryJar task.

```
def allTrees = [
        fileTree(dir: "src/test/groovy"),
        fileTree(dir: "/tmp")
]

task testLibraryJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'testlib'
    from allTrees
}
```